# Write to an input node in the dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write to an input element in the DOM,but i am not getting any expected result.

I tried caching it by attaching it to a variable,then i used the write method on the variable.The code is below.

```
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
    input.write(50);
    //i tried the code below also//
    input.write('50');
    //result was an error which says "input.write is not a function"//
```

Comment: It's `document` not `Document` and getElement**s**ByClassName  instead of `getElementByClassName`. And there is not write method in `HTMLCollection `

Comment: @adiga,i have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
input[0].value = 50;
```